# ERROR 18254 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter : in SpringBoot

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, backend

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2023-08-23T18:50:48.564+05:30 ERROR 18254 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I tried to start my spring boot project and expected it to run normally

Comment: can you provide your `yml` configuration file or `application.properties` file ?

Comment: Sorry , I accidentally deleted the file

Comment: if you want to have a database in the project, you should add params like database url, username, password  in configuration file